# Edit Parent page drop menu when creating a page

Tags: pages, metabox, page-attributes

Please can someone tell me how to remove all items from the 'Parent' drop down when creating a page apart from a few items? (Loop through and remove all that are the ones I want).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [page_attributes_dropdown_pages_args](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/page_attributes_dropdown_pages_args/) filter to remove whatever you want. It's based off of the [wp_dropdown_pages()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_dropdown_pages) arguments so you can use the `exclude` parameter to remove certain pages or a fake parent to remove all the pages:

```
/**
 * Filter the arguments of Page Attributes Parent Dropdown
 *
 * @param Array $args - List of wp_dropdown_pages() arguments
 * @param WP_Post Object $post - Current post object
 *
 * @retun Array $args - List of wp_dropdown_pages() arguments
 */
function admin_page_attributes_meta_filter( $args, $post ) {

    $args['exclude'] = array( 1 );      // Exclude page ID 1 from the dropdown list

    /*
     * Uncomment to exclude all pages
     * $args['child_of'] = -1;
     */

    return $args;

}
add_filter( 'page_attributes_dropdown_pages_args', 'admin_page_attributes_meta_filter', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: Thats great thanks!
Just a note to others, you can use the code to exclude all pages and then $args['include'] to set certain parent pages if required.